# Help to prove this combinatorial lemma

Tags: elementary-set-theory, combinatorial-proofs

Let $V_1,V_2 \subseteq \{1, \dots , n\}.$ Consider the function
$$F(V_1,V_2)= \sum_{\substack{ U \subseteq\{1, \dots,n\} \\  V_1 \cup V_2 \subseteq U}}  (-\iota )^{card(U - V_1)+card(U-V_2)}$$
Then $F(V_1,V_2)=0$ provided $V_1 \cup V_2 \ne \{1, \dots , n\}.$
This lemma is in a research paper. Can anyone help in proving the lemma?
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Take $x\in\{1,\ldots,n\}\setminus(V_1\cup V_2)$. If $U$ contains $V_1\cup V_2$, then so does $U':=U\Delta\{x\}$, and we can check that $(-1)^{|U-V_1|+|U-V_2|}+(-1)^{|U'-V_1|+|U'-V_2|}=0$.

Answer (score 0):

We write $U=(V_1 \cup V_2)\cup \hat U$ with $\hat U \cap (V_1 \cup V_2)= \emptyset.$ This determine $\hat U$ uniquely. Now

$$card(U-V_1)+card(U-V_2)=card(((V_1 \cup V_2)-V_1)\cup \hat U)+card(((V_1 \cup V_2)-V_2)\cup \hat U).$$
Since $ (V_1 \cup V_2)-V_i$ and $\hat U$ are disjoint for $i=1,2$ we get

$$card(U-V_1)+card(U-V_2)=card((V_1 \cup V_2)-V_1)+card((V_1 \cup V_2)-V_2) + 2 card(\hat U).$$
In the last line, the first two summands do not depend on $\hat U$ so we get

$$  \sum_{\substack{ U \\  V_1 \cup V_2 \subseteq U}}  (-\iota )^{card(U - V_1)+card(U-V_2)}=(-\iota )^{card((V_1 \cup V_2)-V_1)+card((V_1 \cup V_2)-V_2)}.\sum_{\substack{\hat U\\ (V_1 \cup V_2) \cap \hat U \ne \emptyset}}(-\iota)^{2.card (\hat U)}$$
$$ =(-\iota )^{card((V_1 \cup V_2)-V_1)+card((V_1 \cup V_2)-V_2)}.\sum_{\substack{\hat U  \subseteq \{1, \dots ,n\}-(V_1 \cup V_2)}}(-1)^{card (\hat U)}$$

This is not the complete proof but can someone tell me up till now is it right or not?, I have doubt in the 2nd last step.

Thank you!

Comment: What is $\iota$?

Comment: it is square root of -1 that is iota